# Json serialization for Object Data Type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

```
public class MyClass
{ 
    public object BidAutoObject { get; set; }
    public bool IsApplied { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class like above and I am creating the Json string from the above Class object. Property "BidAutoObject " is of type "object". The object may be "CxDays" or "AMPM". It is setting dynamically. I am using newtonsoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize the C# object to Json string. The outpout of Json serialization is like

```
"BidAutoObject": {
    "IsSun": true,
    "IsMon": false,
    "IsTue": true,
    "IsWed": true,
    "IsThu": false,
    "IsFri": true,
    "IsSat": true
}
```

So I couldn't identify whether "BidAutoObject type is "CxDays" or "AMPM" from the above json string. how can I add the type information during the serialization process. Do I need to add any attribute to "BidAutoObject "?

```
public class CxDays
{
    public bool IsSun { get; set; }
    public bool IsMon { get; set; }
    public bool IsTue { get; set; }
}

public class AMPM
{
   public bool AM { get; set; }
   public bool PM { get; set; }
   public bool MIX { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of ""BidAutoObject":  in the Json string, I need the class object name such as "CxDays" or "AMPM" in the json string. We have one option using "Jsonserializer setting" .When we set TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto - this will add a $type property ONLY for instances where the declared type (i.e. Base) does not match the instance type (i.e. Derived). But it showing the full namespace of that class.Now I want to show only the class name in the Json string instead of full name space.

Comment: This really looks like the XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you as developer cannot identify which concrete object it is, how do you expect a framework such as JSON.NET to be able to?

Comment: *But it showing the full namespace of that class* -- so what is the problem?  From your description, it sounds as though Json.NET is successfully serializing and deserializing the type information.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is the `TypeNameHandling` in the `JsonSerializerSettings` which you need to add for de- and serialization. 
Just set it to `TypeNameHandling.Auto` which will add a type property to the json for instances which have a type not equal to the declared type.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply don't want the assembly name and namespace name to appear in the JSON for some reason (why?), you can create your own custom subclass of [`DefaultSerializationBinder`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultSerializationBinder.cs) and then set it in [`JsonSerializerSettings.Binder`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Binder.htm):

```
public class DefaultAssemblyBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder
{
    public string DefaultAssemblyName { get; private set; }
    public string DefaultNamespaceName { get; private set; }

    public DefaultAssemblyBinder(string defaultAssemblyName, string defaultNamespaceName)
    {
        this.DefaultAssemblyName = defaultAssemblyName;
        this.DefaultNamespaceName = defaultNamespaceName;
    }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultAssemblyName))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyName))
                assemblyName = DefaultAssemblyName;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultNamespaceName))
        {
            if (typeName != null && !typeName.Contains("."))
                typeName = DefaultNamespaceName + "." + typeName;
        }
        return base.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
    }

    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        base.BindToName(serializedType, out assemblyName, out typeName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultAssemblyName) && assemblyName != null)
            if (assemblyName == DefaultAssemblyName)
                assemblyName = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultNamespaceName) && typeName != null)
        {
            int index = typeName.LastIndexOf('.');
            if (index < 0)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Type {0} does not exist in any namespace, but a default namespace {1} has been set", serializedType.FullName, DefaultNamespaceName));
            if (index == DefaultNamespaceName.Length && string.Compare(DefaultNamespaceName, 0, typeName, 0, index, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                typeName = typeName.Substring(index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, later:

```
        var test = new MyClass { IsApplied = true, BidAutoObject = new CxDays { IsMon = false, IsSun = true, IsTue = false } };

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto, Binder = new DefaultAssemblyBinder(typeof(MyClass).Assembly.FullName, typeof(MyClass).Namespace) };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Creates the following JSON:

> ```
> {
>   "BidAutoObject": {
>     "$type": "CxDays",
>     "IsSun": true,
>     "IsMon": false,
>     "IsTue": false
>   },
>   "IsApplied": true
> }
> ```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMbHQB).

For another custom binder example, see [Custom SerializationBinder](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) from the documentation.